# Ngrx-data select a single entity

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am using ngrx-data plugin (runs on top of ngrx), and I'm trying to select a single entity from the store (that ngrx data calls 'Cache'). I found that you can add a single entity to the cache but I can't find the way to retrieve a single item (based on Id) from the store.

**Do I have to write my own selector for this?** I would assume a simple operation like this would be provided by ngrx-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but I was able to get a single entity by using the collection$ property on the data service.

for example, I have an entity called Core and an EntityService called CoreEntityService.  My entity cache has been populated through the coreEntityService.getByKey(id).  Or I could have populated the entity cache by a getAll().

when I want to retrieve the core with that id I use this construct, illustrated here by logging the single entity to the console:

`this.coreEntityService.collection$.subscribe(collection => console.log(collection.entities[id]))`

Edited to Add:

you can also subscribe to entity service's entityMap$.  I added a method to my entity service called selectEntityById like this which works well and returns an observable, unlike the previous code, which returns an actual object:

```
selectEntityById(coreId: number): Observable<Core> {
return this.entityMap$.pipe(
  map(entities => entities[coreId]),
  first());
}
```

The documentation for ngrx/data is not great at the moment but it is improving.  I'm hoping that someone will post a better answer to this question soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and arrived at a slightly different result.  This is not necessarily any better than the other answer, but it does work in a slightly different manner.

Just as [glitchbane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225512/glitchbane) [said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995850/2386511), the documentation is a work in progress so I am also hoping that I am missing some readily available method to do this provided by ngrx-data, but I have yet to find one.

I wanted my subscription to provide the single element I was looking for rather than using the `id` to select the element inside the subscription.  This lead me to creating a selector.

Imports and Selector:

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EntityCollection } from '@ngrx/data';
import { MyModel } from '....my.model';

export const selectMyModels =
    (entities: EntityCollection<MyModel>) => entities.entities;

export const selectMyModelById = (id: number) => createSelector(
    selectMyModels,
    entities => entities[id]
);
```

Example usage:

```
this.myModelEntityCollectionService.collection$.pipe(
    select(selectMyModelById(1)))                    // <-- used here
        .subscribe((myModel: MyModel) => {
            this.myLogger.log(JSON.stringify(myModel));
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I start using **Ngrx-data** not along time ago...I supposed you can create selectors in other ways.

However, I will explain how I used to do for entities coming directly from our model, cache and so on ... What I am doing is importing the service in the constructor

```
  constructor(private myModelsService: myModelEntityService) { }
```

And then for example getting all the entities with

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.entities$ = this.myModelsService.entities$;
}
```

Finally, to solve your problem that it is just to take a saved entity from your store or as is the same rescuing from the observable of entities; I would catch the entity up like below

```
this.myEntity$ = this.myModelsService.entities$.pipe(mergeAll(), take(n), last())
```

Basically, your are doing an emission for every entities with **mergeAll** (decomposing an array), cutting them with **take** and setting the "n" that you want (let's say you need the third element, then n="3") and completing the emissions with **last** so you just have this element.

I hope it helps you or may give you the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

We need somehow to use this

`  constructor(private authDataService: AuthDataService,
              private authEntityService: AuthEntityService,
              private authEntitySelectorFactory: AuthEntitySelectorFactory)

const collectionSelectors = authEntitySelectorFactory.createCollectionSelector('auth');

collectionSelectors.projector   ??
`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)